# how to custom material ui all components size?

Tags: material-ui, size, spacing

i want set all material mui components size,like Button,TextField,ButtonGroup,all of it.

for now,i use createTheme

```
const theme=createTheme({
 components:{
    MuiButtonGroup:{
                defaultProps:{
                    size:'small'
                }
            }
 }
})
```

one by one set, is any other way to set all?

and i set spacing:4,why the input components padding still 8.5px 14px in small?